# Syled-components use theme property in custom component property

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm having an issue passing styled-components theme to a custom property on a custom component. I know that you can use the theme prop like this:

```
export const LinkButton = styled((props) => (
    <Text {...props}>{props.children}</Text>
))`
    color: ${(props: ThemeProps) => props.theme.colors.secondaryColorBlue};
`;
```

but I'm having an issue with how to use the theme property whenever I'm using it as a prop on a custom component:

```
export const ButtonPrimary = styled((props) => (
    <CustomButton
        {...props}
        textColor={(props: ThemeProps) => props.theme.colors.white}
    />
))`
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: ${(props: ThemeProps) =>
        props.theme.colors.secondaryColorBlue};
`;
```

Is there a way to do this? Or maybe a better implementation that I can use to do this?

Comment: why don't u just call the theme in the `CustomButton` component instead of passing it in `textColor`? I mean, in the file where you have the `CustomButton` just make it that it have the `theme.colors.white`

Comment: @garjted the issue with that is I also use that `CustomButton` component for a `SecondaryButton` and `NegativeButton` that would use different text colors. Sure I guess I could pass a prop of `type` or something and then select the correct theme color based on the type, but I didn't know if there was another way to do this the way I currently have it implemented since it would be less of a refactor

Comment: `textColor={props.theme.colors.white}`, have you try this?

Comment: @garjted yes, that will just respond with an error saying cannot read property 'colors' of undefined since it's reading from the actual properties that were sent to the component like `onPress` and `title`

Comment: you can check out styled-component `attrs`, it might be suitable for your problem. I'll show you an example when I finish work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @garjted for letting me know about `attrs` that looks like that fixed the issue.

I just had to change this:

```
export const ButtonPrimary = styled((props) => (
    <CustomButton
        {...props}
        textColor={(props: ThemeProps) => props.theme.colors.white}
    />
))`
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: ${(props: ThemeProps) =>
        props.theme.colors.secondaryColorBlue};
`;
```

To this:

```
export const ButtonPrimary = styled(CustomButton).attrs((props) => ({
    textColor: props.theme.colors.white,
}))`
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: ${(props: ThemeProps) =>
        props.theme.colors.secondaryColorBlue};
`;
```

And that solved my issue.